# Create a new RecalculateAction for a hybris voter

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to create a voter for a specific URL but the documentation doesn't help me very much. I want to understand what `RecalculateAction` means because I want to execute a specific business logic within that voter and I would like to extend this enum, the only problem is that I can't find an example in the 1905 project.

At the moment, I've tried to create a voter by implementing `de.hybris.platform.personalizationservices.voters.Voter` like they say in the documentation for a `CustomVoter`, but I would like to use the `ConfigurableUrlVoter` and this is why I wanted to know how are these `RecalculateAction` enums used? Something like:

```
if(recalculateActions.contains(RecalculateAction.RECALCULATE)){
   doSomething();
}
if(recalculateActions.contains(RecalculateAction.UPDATE)){
   doSomethingElse();
} .... ?
```

Or do I need to create some new class for the new `RecalculateAction` enum ?

**DOC URL:** https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2005/en-US/a24c6902dfce4bf9b5624ab4dcf7834d.html?q=voter

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2005/en-US/25e2d4376ebc4cc39200a52416a4fbd9.html), the recalculation actions do the following:

- RECALCULATE: recalculates customization results and stores them in the session.
- UPDATE: updates information about the user segments.
- ASYNC_PROCESS: starts an asynchronous process to update user segments and calculate customization results to be stored in the database.
- LOAD: loads customization results stored in database as a result of asynchronous calculation process.

If you need to extend this enum, or create a new class depends on what you want to solve